# Can Cloudwatch provide server or elb details in alarm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a bunch of ELBs setup across multiple regions, and I'd like to know generally when a server falls out of rotation on one of them. I setup an alarm `across all lbs` on `UnhealthyHostCount`. That works great in general, but when one server falls out of rotation, the only thing the alarm tells me is that some server fell out of rotation, without any information about where that happened, or what server it was:

```
Alarm Details:
- Name:                       ServerOutOfRotation
- Description:                Some server falls out of rotation
- State Change:               OK -> ALARM
- Reason for State Change:    Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (1.0) was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0).
- Timestamp:                  Sunday 08 November, 2015 13:55:39 UTC
- AWS Account:                1234

Threshold:
- The alarm is in the ALARM state when the metric is GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold 1.0 for 60 seconds. 

Monitored Metric:
- MetricNamespace:            AWS/ELB
- MetricName:                 UnHealthyHostCount
- Dimensions:                 
- Period:                     60 seconds
- Statistic:                  Maximum
- Unit:                       not specified
```

Is there any way to have this provided, or do I have to setup separate alarms on each load balancer to get at this information?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The Elastic Load Balancing service will not provide specific details about which Amazon EC2 instance is failing a health check.

Setting up "separate alarms on each load balancer" will not assist. You would need to set them up on each individual EC2 instance, which can be difficult if Auto Scaling is in use (since instances are added and removed).

If Auto Scaling is configured to use an ELB health check, then it will terminate and replace any instances that fail the health check.